# $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{n^{100}}{2^n}$, prove using epsilon definition

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I want to prove that $0$ is a limit of the sequence.

Hence, $\forall \epsilon > 0 \ \ \exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n> \mathbb{N}$ we have $\frac{n^{100}}{2^n}<\epsilon$.

I tried to use the induction to show that $n^{100} < \epsilon 2^n \Rightarrow (n+1)^{100} < \epsilon 2^{n+1}$

or

$n^{100} + \sum_{k=1}^{99} \binom{100}{k} n^k < \epsilon 2^n + \epsilon 2^n$
but I'm not sure about $\sum_{k=1}^{99} \binom{100}{k} n^k < \epsilon 2^n$. Tried to see when $n^{100} > \sum_{k=1}^{99} \binom{100}{k} n^k$, but it didn't seem to help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $n\geqslant200$ we have 
$$
\begin{aligned}
2^n&=(1+1)^n\\\\&>\binom{n}{101}\\\\&=\dfrac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-100)}{101!}\\\\&>\dfrac{n^{101}}{2^{101}\cdot101!}
\end{aligned}
$$

and hence $$\tag1\dfrac{n^{100}}{2^n}<\dfrac{2^{101}\cdot101!}{n}\hspace{31pt}\forall n\geqslant200.$$

Now let $\varepsilon>0$ be be given. Since $\mathbb N$ is not bounded from above, there exists some natural number $N$ such that $N>\dfrac{2^{101}\cdot101!}{\varepsilon}\iff\varepsilon>\dfrac{2^{101}\cdot101!}{N}.$ It follows from $(1)$ that $\dfrac{n^{100}}{2^n}<\varepsilon$ for each $n\geqslant N+200$ and hence $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{n^{100}}{2^n}=0.$$

Comment: this is not $\varepsilon$-$N$ : P

Comment: Just set $N=\lfloor\frac{2^{101}\cdot 101!}{\varepsilon}\rfloor+1$ and you'll have your $\varepsilon-N$ proof ;-)

Comment: now,..  it is : )

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the ratio of the $n^{th}$ term to by its successor is:

$${(1+1/n)\over 2}^{100}$$

Clearly, there exists an $N$ such that the ratio is less than one.